# Having trouble with this code

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble getting this particular piece of code to compile,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#pragma hdrstop
using namespace std;
#include <tchar.h>
void mark(int)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << " Enter a Students Mark: ";
    cin  >> mark;

    if (mark >= 80 )
    cout << "A" ;
    else
        if (mark >= 65)
            cout << " B" ;
                else
                    if (mark >= 50 )
                        cout << "c";
                        else
                            {
                            numberFailed += 1;
                            if (mark >= 40 )
                                cout << "D"
                                    else
                                        cout << "E";

                            }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If anybody can point me in the right direction this would be most appreciated. 
The Compiler in Embarcadero Highlights the following line 
int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

and gives me the error message [bcc32 Error] Student Marks.cpp(18): E2141 Declaration syntax error

Am lost on this.

Comment: Welcome to your new hobby as a programmer.  In this case, you're lucky that someone quickly spotted a syntax error in your code.  However, in general we expect to see the actual compiler error.  Believe it or not, your compiler will actually tell you the problem.  If you don't understand the error message and want to ask for help, it's important to provide that error message as part of your question.  For further advice on how to post a good question on StackOverflow, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What problems you faced, please give some information about the problems or error you encountered.

Comment: Did you mean `if (mark >= 50 ) cout << " C";`?

Comment: @MohitJain It looks like that should be the case.  I don't know why you deleted your answer.  There's also an issue with an extra close parenthesis on the first condition: `mark >= 80`

Comment: Cheers guys for the speedy response :) [bcc32 Error] Student Marks.cpp(18): E2141 Declaration syntax error is the error message im getting I am using Embarcadero RAD studio XE8

Comment: `int_tmain` should be `int _tmain`, but you shouldn't use `_tmain` anyway. Use `int main (int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: @paddy My answer was based on certain assumptions. Unless Question author himself clears what does he want to ask, I guess it would be wrong to answer.

Comment: @Mikey101 The question is badly formatted, can you please read the suggestion in first comment and improve the question.

Comment: And just sitting here, I spot more issues.  One with the main function, already mentioned.  And `mark` is defined as a function prototype with no semi-colon, but used as an int value.  `numberFailed` is not declared.  Wow, it feels like we're taking on the job of a compiler here....

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have asked about is here:

```
void mark(int)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) // This line here
```

That first line is a function declaration, which needs to be terminated by a semi-colon.  Because the lines that follow are comments and preprocessor directives, the compiler doesn't know anything is wrong until it hits the `main` definition.

The naive solution is to add the semi-colon (and to fix the `main` definition which is also broken):

```
void mark(int);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

However, looking at the rest of your code, it's clear that `mark` is not a function at all.  It's an integer.  So you should remove that line altogether and declare `mark` in your `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int mark = 0;
    int numberFailed = 0;

    cout << " Enter a Students Mark: ";
    cin  >> mark;

    if (mark >= 80 )
        cout << "A" ;
    else if (mark >= 65)
        cout << " B" ;
    else if (mark >= 50 )
        cout << "C";
    else
    {
        numberFailed++;   ///< You don't actually use this value
        if (mark >= 40 )
            cout << "D"
        else
            cout << "E";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Notice I've also added `numberFailed` which you forgot to declare.  And since you're new it's good practice to always initialise your values when you declare them, which will save you some tears one day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (just an idea):

```
int main()
{
int mark;int numberFailed;
char y;
do
{
 cout << "Enter Student's Mark: ";
 cin >> mark;
 if (mark >= 80 )
 {cout <<"A";}
 else if (mark >= 65)
 {cout <<"B";}
 else if (mark >= 50 )
 {cout <<"c";}
 else
 {
    numberFailed += 1;  // i don't know what to do with this ?
    if (mark >= 40 )
    cout <<"D";
    else
    cout <<"E";
 }
 cout<<"\nDo you want to enter more numbers ? (y/n) : ";
 cin>>y;
} while(y=='y');   // loop for entering more numbers
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for all the quick and helpful responses :) Program is now functional